# Why i get this AttributeError when form is submitted

Tags: django

I'm having an error when I submit a form. When it loads this is the error I'm getting: 'list' object has no attribute 'imageuploader_profile

```
@login_required
def upload(request):
    PostFormSet = modelformset_factory(Image, fields=('image',), extra=2)
    formset = PostFormSet(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            post = formset.save(commit=False)
            post.imageuploader_profile = request.user
            post.save()
            for f in formset:
                try:
                    file = Image(
                        imageuploader_profile=post,
                        image=f.cleaned_data['image'],
                        image_caption=f.cleaned_data['image_caption'],
                        tag_someone=f.cleaned_data['tag_someone'],
                    )
                    file.save()
                except:
                    break
    else:
        formset = PostFormSet(queryset=Image.objects.none())
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {"formset": formset})

<form action="{% url 'site:upload' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {%csrf_token%}
        {{ formset }}
         <button type="submit">Post</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: It is a *formset*, hence the result of `formset.save(commit=False) is a *list* of `Image`s, not a single one.

Comment: @Willen okay, how do i make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with a form**set**, hence that means that `formset.save(commit=False)` will return a *list* of objects. You can thus iterate over that list with:

```
# …
if formset.is_valid():
    posts = formset.save(commit=False)
    for post in posts:
        post.imageuploader_profile = request.user
        post.save()
# …
```

you should *not* iterate over the `formset` itself.

Comment: when i sumbit the post now i get name 'posts' is not defined

Comment: @Hi3e: did you rewrite `post = formset.save()` to `posts = ...`. Please try to *understand* what is happening, not just copying.

Comment: Can you help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60157046/saving-data-to-admin-using-form